# A question about Android recovery bootup sequence

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, fastboot, partitions

What exactly gets copied into the `/recovery` partition when I execute the following command:

```
fastboot flash recovery <my_recovery_image>.img
```

As per my understanding, the recovery image contains the kernel image and the ramdisk (`initrd.img`). So these should go into the `/boot` partition (am I right?). So, what is the content of `/recovery` partition after flashing the device with custom recovery when I explicitly specify `recovery` partition argument in the `fastboot` command? Or the `/boot` and `/recovery` partitions have separate versions of kernels and ramdisks, where `/boot` partition ramdisk would help load the operating system image from `/system` partition? If this is true, does that mean there are more than one `init.rc` scripts? (one to mount some partitions during recovery boot-up and the other for normal OS boot-up)?